# Python Statistics File

Tags: python, statistics

I've created a python guessing game but now I want to be able to save the game statistics to a file at the end of each game. For each game the statistics to be recorded include the player name, their play status(win or loss) and the number of tries. I need the game to be saved in this format:

Username|status|number of guesses

If anyone could help me with that, that would be kind.
This is the code I have for the game:

```
import random

number = random.randint(1, 100)

player_name = input("Hello, What's your name?: ")

number_of_guesses = 0   

print("Okay! "+ player_name+ " I am guessing a number between 1 and 100:")


max_guesses = random.randint(1, 6)

print("You have " + str(max_guesses) + " guesses. ")

while number_of_guesses < max_guesses:

    guess = int(input())

    number_of_guesses += 1

    if guess < number:

        print("Your guess is too low")

    if guess > number:

        print("Your guess is too high")

    if guess == number:

        break

if guess == number:

    print("You guessed the number in " + str(number_of_guesses) + " tries!")

else:

    print("You did not guess the number, the number was " + str(number))

f = open("Statistics.txt", "a")

f.write(player_name), (number_of_guesses)

f.close()

f = open("Statistics.txt", "r")

print(f.read())
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve the problem? Can you share the code you’ve already written?

Comment: As @BillHorvath mentioned, just test around a bit with the guide I linked you in the last question. If you get stuck, just post the code you tried and we are happy to help.

Comment: Could you take a look now?

Comment: @HammadRana if you look at your code, where exactly are you saving your variables with the username, status and the number of guesse  into the file you create?

Comment: how would I add a variable to determine if the player won or loss?

Comment: You could for example declare a string variable, let's call it `did_win`. You already know from your if-else statement, which determines if `guess == number`, if the player did win or not. So you could then just set `did_win` to "won!" in case the winning message is printed and to "lost!" in case the loosing message is printed. 
Then just append the `did_win` variable to your file with `f.write(did_win)`